# Java метод deepToString() не работает с int[], но работает с int[][]

Tags: java

Имеется следующий код:

```
int[] arr1 = {10, 20, 30, 40};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr1));
```

Здесь компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[]

При этом следующий код компилируется без ошибок:

```
int[][] arr2 = {{10, 20}, {30, 40}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr1));
```

Почему `int[]` не может конвертироваться в `Object`? Разве массивы примитивов не являются объектами? И почему при этом двумерный массив примитивов `int[][]` в `Object` прекрасно конвертируется?

Comment: Если вы посмотрите текст ошибки, то увидите, что кастуется в `Object[]`, а совсем не в `Object`. А скастоваться в этом случае он не может, потому что примитивы не являются наследниками Object.

Comment: А `int[][]` - уже не примитив и от `Object` наследуется?

Comment: `int[]` тоже не примитив. JVM смотрит, какой тип содержится в массиве и можно ли к нему привести тип содержимого текущего массива.

Answer (score 3):

Всё правильно говорит.

`int[]` - `Object`, а `int[][]` это массив `Object`ов (`Object[]`, где каждый элемент - `int[]`), то есть массив массивов, где внутренний массив является объектом. `int[]` - массив примитивов, который не умеет автобокситься в `Integer[]` (вы ведь на это намекаете в вопросе?).
Запутанно, но, надеюсь, понятно.

Для примитивных одномерных массивов есть `Arrays.toString(...)`